# Hide private child control property at design time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a container control with some private child control. How to hide the property browser from showing the control at design time. also it shows a lock and a square icon on each of the control at design time.

[image]

I tried to set for the control

```
<Browsable(False), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden), Bindable(False)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
```

also tried to set `<DesignTimeVisible(False), ToolboxItem(False)>` for the child control. but still shows up in the designer even though it is not editable.

Currently I am painting the control at design time and on runtime loading the real control. is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - Set GenerateMember = false**

In the design mode of the base control, set [`GenerateMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties) property of the child control to `false`. This way the derived control wont allow selection of the button.

**Option 2 - Using TypeDescriptor set a new non-working designer for the child control**

Another trick is setting a new non-working designer for child control using `typeDescriptor.AddAttributes`, in the constructor of the base control, after initialize components:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.button1, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
```

Comment: Always use the first solution, unless you find a scenario which you cannot apply the first one. Then choose the second solution.

Comment: Thanks the second option worked. when the `GenerateMember = false` the child controls become useless as they cannot be referred in other parts of the control.

Comment: Cool, no problem :) If you need to refer them (and not just handle their events), then I agree, it's a valid scenario for second option.