# How to hide some objects from a Custom Property in WinForms Designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, designer

I have a `UserControl` which contains for example a property

```
public Button TargetButton { get; set; }
```

the `UserControl` also contains for example 3 buttons.

Now i have a Main UI or Control that inherits from this `UserControl`

The UI Control has a `Button` . Now i was thought the TargetButton in PropertyGrid or VS Desginer will show only Buttons in UiControl. but actually it shows all buttons. the Core Buttons of `UserControl` and the normal buttons in UI Control.

How to Exclude Buttons of UserControl from PropertyGrid or VS Designer TargetButton property selecting list ?

For example : Attribute in UserControl like

```
[TypeConverter(ExcludeObjects(coreBtn1, coreBtn2 ))]
```

So all i need preventing My Property selecting the Core Buttons on Base UserControl. but only i can selects a buttons in Main Control or UIControl which inherits from UserControl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57034662/3110834

Comment: Reza Aghaei, thank you . it works very very well with Generate Member